ExoPlayer not playing HLS video
I want to make a sample test video player, here I will test hls links. But after clicking the "Play Now" button the player view appears but no video plays. I want to play the link url inserted to the TextField after clicking Play Now. The player appears with some buttons but does not play any stream.
Code -

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            HomeView()
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun HomeView() {
    var text by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
    var url by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }

    PlayerXTheme {
        Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(20.dp),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
                    SimpleOutlinedTextFieldSample(text) { text = it }
                    Button(
                        onClick = { url = text },
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(top = 16.dp)
                    ) {
                        Text("Play Now")
                    }

                    if (url.isNotEmpty()) {
                        ExoPlayerView(url = url)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun SimpleOutlinedTextFieldSample(text: String, onTextChange: (String) -> Unit) {
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = onTextChange,
        label = { Text("HLS/M3U8 URL") },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(60.dp)
    )
}

@Composable
fun ExoPlayerView(url: String) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val exoPlayer = remember {
        ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build().apply {
            val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(url)
            setMediaItem(mediaItem)
            prepare()
            playWhenReady = true
        }
    }

    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        exoPlayer.addListener(object : Player.Listener {
            override fun onIsPlayingChanged(isPlaying: Boolean) {
                super.onIsPlayingChanged(isPlaying)
                Log.d("ExoPlayerView", "IsPlaying: $isPlaying")
            }

            override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(state: Int) {
                super.onPlaybackStateChanged(state)
                Log.d("ExoPlayerView", "PlaybackState: $state")
            }
        })

        onDispose {
            exoPlayer.release()
        }
    }

    AndroidView(
        factory = {
            PlayerView(context).apply {
                player = exoPlayer
            }
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(200.dp)
    )
}


I want to play HLS using Jetpack Compose.
